# image inside drop down box

Tags: jquery, html, image

I need to have image inside the drop down box using the html and php. Can i place image tag inside option tag. Is there any plugin in jQuery to show it. The problem is in IE.

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, so tag removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a class to each select item by hand and assign a background image. e.g:

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option class="email">Email</option>
    <option class="phone">Phone</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.email {
    background:url(path-toyour-icon.png) left top no-repeat #fff;
    padding-left: WITH_OF_YOUR_ICON;
}
.phone {
    background:url(path-toyour-icon.png) left top no-repeat #fff;
    padding-left: WITH_OF_YOUR_ICON;
}
```